# Mac doesn't not accept to create folder name ".service" on Finder

Tags: terminal, finder

Using Visual Studio I created a Project in a folder named "something.Service" It works file without problem. The same happens if I export this project to a Windows machine.

When I look on it via Finder the folder has an extension called ".app" and it is not accessible via Finder.

When I try to access this folder via Terminal there is no problem.

On this print screen, I show this discrepancy on Finder and Terminal

[image]

Why I can't use this Name on Finder?

Comment: Is this executable a GUI or command line program?

Comment: This is a .net core program, but It happens with any folder any where named as .Service

Comment: Sorry that doesn't answer the question is it a GUI app or a command line non GUI program?

Comment: To be honest with you, this project is only DLL. Outside of Visual studio, it is only text files.

Comment: macOS does not have DLLs so makes not sense. Shared libraries are .so or .dylib or directories .bundle. Windows DLLS are .dll (.Net might be the same)

Comment: I don't think you understood. In Visual Studio I'm writing code that will create Dll. But What causes the issue, as I create a folder from visual studio (similar to X-code) with the name AFetter.Battlefield.Services and when I got this folder to send to someone else I notice one of the folders "AFetter.Battlefield.Services" was renamed to AFetter.Battlefield.Services.app and was accessible anymore. I think we can leave what I was doing out of this conversation.

Comment: No we need to know exactly what you are doing so we can try to replicate and then work out what each step is doing

Comment: Easy, open finder and create a folder named MyFriend.Service or Open terminal and create the folder with this name and verify later on Finder what happens. Or Install visual studio, create a solution, solution name MyFriend, add a new project to this solution called MyFriend.Service :)

Answer (score 1):

This is because `.service` extension is special. I can't find information on why, but it's treated as an application.

You cannot avoid this in Finder. If the filename ends in `.service`, it will behave this way. If you want to view the contents of the folder, right click and choose "Show Package Contents."

It won't impact the file system or other applications.

Comment: Services are special porgrams that run from any well written app. there is a services menu in the app name menu. https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp1012/mac

Comment: Yes - but these aren't services. Services live in the Library/Services folder and have a `.workflow` extension.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/SysServices/Articles/providing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000853-98262 says that thgey do have a .service extension. I think .workflow is if done with automator or similar

Comment: Ah - I see. Fair enough.